# error while installation of react-router-dom

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

PS "my project file" npm install react-router-dom

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: google-maps-react@2.0.6

npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.0

npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react

npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1

npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled

npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.7.0

npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material

npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.6.2

npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material

npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)

npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)

npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.7.0

npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material

npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.6.2

npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material

npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.6.2" from the root project

npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)

npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)

npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1

npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled

npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.7.0

npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material

npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.6.2

npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material

npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.6.2" from the root project

npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)

npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.7.0

npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine

npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.7.0" from @mui/system@5.7.0

npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system

npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.7.0" from @mui/material@5.7.0

npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material

npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/system, the root project)

npm ERR!   16 more (@mui/base, @mui/icons-material, @mui/material, ...)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from google-maps-react@2.0.6

npm ERR! node_modules/google-maps-react

npm ERR!   google-maps-react@"^2.0.6" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from google-maps-react@2.0.6

npm ERR!   node_modules/google-maps-react

npm ERR!     google-maps-react@"^2.0.6" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR!

npm ERR! For a full report see:

npm ERR! C:\Users\Darsh Pawar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-20T15_18_27_612Z-eresolve-report.txt

this is the error is displaying while installing react-router-dom, please explain and give solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be good if you could share your package.json, but as I can see in the message, the problem actually is on the package for google maps:

> npm ERR! While resolving: google-maps-react@2.0.6
> npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0

probably it is because you have a not compatible react version with google maps package.
Also check if the version of react-router-dom is compatible with your react version!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missing or outdated peer dependencies. Specifically you have React 18 and several of your dependencies only accept up to React 16 or so. Check that you have correctly installed all project dependencies. You may need to update to later versions of dependencies that work with React 18.

For example, bump to `google-maps-react@2.0.8` to support React 18.

[package.json](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/package.json)

```json
{
  "name": "google-maps-react",
  "version": "2.0.8",
  "description": "Google maps container",
  "author": "Fullstack.io <us@fullstack.io>",
  "license": "MIT",
  ...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Check through all your dependencies and update any that are incompatible with your version of React.

Alternatively, if you think it's safe you could try the suggestion to forcefully install dependencies with the `--force` flag, or to use legacy peer dependencies with the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag.

Examples:

- `npm i <package name> --force`
- `npm i <package name> --legacy-peer-deps`

Or if you are just installing the project dependencies from a fresh repo cloning:

- `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`